# Como enviar um HREF com método POST ou disfarçar?

Tags: php, html, formulário, post

Gostaria que a partir do meu href, ele fosse para a página "spincoin.php" com o método post, enviando a variável "1", como eu posso fazer isso?

Código:

```
<div>
    <a href="spincoin.php">
        <h2>Product</h2>
        <p>Cost: 100P</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Por quê não fazer isso utilizando o elemento `form` mesmo?

Comment: Sou um pouco leigo em HTML e fiz da maneira que eu achava certo, não sei como ficaria para fazer com o form, já que ele só aceita inputs (eu acho). Caso dê para fazer com o form, como ficaria?

Comment: Você pode enganar o usuário, fazê-lo pensar que é um link

Comment: edita a pergunta que tenho um exemplo pronto

Comment: Como eu faço isso? Pode me mandar o exemplo? @LeoCaracciolo

Comment: edita a pergunta, Como enviar um href com método POST, e se não for possível, pelo menos disfarçar

Comment: mas no seu exemplo fica um pouco complicado o link abraça muita coisa, img, h2, p, p

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo desta maneira?

Comment: tinha esquecido o metodo post

Comment: [Aqui mostra com fazer usando JavaScript](http://blog.rdtecnologia.com.br/php/passando-dados-via-post-em-javascript/) http://blog.rdtecnologia.com.br/php/passando-dados-via-post-em-javascript/ Saudações,
Itamar M. Lins Jr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu acho impossível método post por url. O que se pode fazer é disfarçar o botão.

Como não queremos que se veja o formulário, só queremos enviar seus dados por POST,  o campo do formulário é hidden, ou seja, oculto.

**1: Botão como se fosse uma imagem**

<sup>O valor a ser passado está no input hidden de name var e value 1</sup>

```css
.tim{
border: 2px solid #AD235E;
border-radius: 100px;
width: 150px;
height: 150px; background-image: url(http://kithomepage.com/sos/kkl.png);
}
.tim:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form action="https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="var" value="1" />
    <button class="tim">
    </button>
</form>
```

**2: Botão como se fosse um link**

```css
.tim {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline;
    background: none;
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: blue;
}
button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form action="https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="var" value="1" />
    <button class="tim">Pagina destino
    </button>
</form>
```

> **Se a informação a ser passada não é relevante pode passar pelo método GET usando um parâmetro na própria URL**    `<a href="spincoin.php?var=1"....`

```
<div style="height:200px;width:350px;position:static;margin-left:120px;border-style:solid">
<a href="spincoin.php?var=1" style="border-bottom: none;">
    <img style="width: 360px;" src="images/btn.png"/>
    <h2 style="color:white;font-size:24px;position:absolule;margin-top:-180px;margin-left:15px;">FREE HACK - Wallhack</h2>
    <p style="margin-left:15px;">See all through the wall with the free hack.</p>
    <p style="margin-right:10px; text-align: right; margin-top:53px; font-size: 25px; color: white">Cost: 100P</p>
  </a>
 /div>
```

e recuperar na página destino da seguinte forma:

```
   $var = $_GET["var"];
```

**Dessa forma vai atender melhor seu HTML**

Comment: tinha esquecido o metodo post

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, vou testar o método get.

Answer (score 4):

Como o @AndersonCarlosWoss comentou, não é possível mandar a um elemento `<a>` usar método `POST` diretamente. Para fazer `POST`, você precisa de um elemento `<form>`:

```
<form method="POST" action="spincoin.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="1" value="1">
    <a href="javascript:document.querySelector('form').submit();">Clique aqui</a>
</form>
```

O elemento `<form>` representa um formulário, que consiste numa série de campos, que são representados pelos elementos `<input>`, `<select>`, `<textarea>` e `<button>` descendentes do formulário.

O `<form>` tem um atributo `method` que diz qual o método HTTP a usar; neste caso, você quer usar `POST`, então é isso que pomos. O atributo `action` indica para qual URL deve ser enviado o formulário.

No caso, este nosso formulário somente tem um campo oculto (isto é, não aparece para o usuário) cujo nome é `1` e cujo valor também é `1`. Há outros tipos de campos visíveis: de texto (`<input type="text">`), *dropdown* (`<select>`), *checkbox* (`<input type="check">`), botões (`<button>` ou `<input type="button">`). Quando o formulário é enviado, ele coleciona todos os seus descendentes que são campos e os envia para a URL de destino com ou o atributo `id` ou o atributo `name` como chave (se ambos estiverem definidos, `id` tem preferência) e o atributo `value` como valor.

Finalmente, normalmente o formulário é enviado clicando num controle `<input type="submit">`, mas com um pouco de *javascript* podemos fazer um *link* comum enviá-lo, usando o *schema* de URL `javascript:`. Basta obter uma referência ao `form` (no exemplo, usando `document.querySelector()` e chamar o método `submit()`. O resto funciona automaticamente.

Um último *caveat*: se você quiser transferir um arquivo anexo (através do controle `<input type="file">`), o `<form>` vai **precisar** ter o atributo `enctype="multipart/form-data"` (o padrão é `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`). De outra forma, o anexo não será enviado.

Comment: Acho que se você utilizar `this.parentNode.submit()` no elemento `a` fica melhor não só em questão de performance, pois o JS não precisa fazer a busca do elemento, como você permite a existência de múltiplos formulários na página.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Naturalmente, existem vários métodos de se obter uma referência ao formulário; escolhi uma a esmo. `this.parentNode` pode ser uma opção, mas não testei para ver se funcionava corretamente ou não. Em todo caso, a ideia era explicar ao OP o que é um elemento `<form>` e quais as suas características para que ele escolha o que serve pra ele e o que não serve, em vez de somente copiar e colar uma resposta pronta.

Answer (score 2):

Olha também podemos utilizar JQuery para fazer um post, exemplo:

```
<?php
 // trecho q devera gerar a saida
 // coloquei .PHP_EOL caso queira interromper a execucao e depurar erros
 $jquery = ''.PHP_EOL; 
 $jquery .= ' var MinhaVarAqui1 = "'.$var1.'";'.PHP_EOL;
 $jquery .= ' var MinhaVarAqui2 = "'.$var1.'";'.PHP_EOL;
 $jquery .= ' var MinhaVarAqui3 = "'.$var1.'";'.PHP_EOL;

 // va declarando as variaveis a serem postadas conforme a necessidade

 // aqui vamos realizar o post sem form
 $.post("INFORME_A_URL_DESEJADA_AQUI ex: http://meusite.com/scripa.php",{ var1:MinhaVarAqui1, var2:MinhaVarAqui2, var3:MinhaVarAqui3 });

 $jquery .= ''.PHP_EOL;
?>
```

Procura ler sobre o .post do jquery ele é muito útil.